# String to time PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, strtotime

How to convert "00:00:00.000 GMT Mon Nov 22 2010" to more user friendly format.

Comment: SO definitely need more questions of this type... </ironic>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//initial format
echo '0:00:00.000 GMT Mon Nov 22 2010';

//unix format: 2010-11-22
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('0:00:00.000 GMT Mon Nov 22 2010'));

//explicit format: Monday 22 November 2010
echo date('l d F Y',strtotime('0:00:00.000 GMT Mon Nov 22 2010'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use these PHP functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

strtotime will convert your current to a unix timestamp.

You can then format that unix time stamp however you want, using date().

Answer (score 2):

Why not with [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?!

```
echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime('0:00:00.000 GMT Mon Nov 22 2010')); // I'm french
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also find these useful:

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
```

And in CakePHP the TimeHelper http://book.cakephp.org/view/1470/Time:

```
echo $time->nice($mysqlDate);

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the string to a datetime using strtotime:
[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

 and then format the datetime anyway you want using sprintf:
[sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function:

```
echo strtotime("00:00:00.000 GMT Mon Nov 22 2010"), "\n";
```

Comment: that depends on the user..."de gustibus non est disputandum", but the idea was to have a function that does the conversion.. the format he can choose by himself. The question was a "how"...

Answer (score 0):

check on php manual and try strtotime and date function